# If 2 action listener are registered for same JButton, then prevent execution of listener2 on certain condition

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I have a JButton, two action listeners are registered for it. `Listener1` will be executed first because it is registered first.
So, what i need is, In a  condition matches in the `Listener1` then the code of  `Listener2` should not be executed.
Would you please help me, how to prevent execution of Listener2 if condition matches in Listener1.

```
JButton jbtn=new JButton();

jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     //Listener1
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         if(condition==true){
             //do not execute the code of listner2
             //stop further executeion of current action
         }
     }

});


jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     //Listener2
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         //some code
     }

});
```

Comment: Why not just add "if !condition then do stuff in second action listener" in the first action listener?

Comment: I agree that you should do as @Doorknob suggests, either use `if (!condition) {...}` in listener 2, or use just use one ActionListener or AbstractAction with the if / else block nested inside.

Comment: 1) See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Actually, Listener1 and Listener2 are registered from different classes. And the class of Listener2 should not be changed. So I should control from Listener1.

Comment: Why do you need two listeners? Why not merge them into one? And it will be easy to use `if` condition on the second part to let it execute or not.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me as if you may be over-complicating things. Why not simply use one ActionListener or AbstractAction and nest the if block inside:

```
jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(condition) { // no need for the == true part!
     myMethod1();
   } else { // condition is false
     myMethod2();
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Listener1 is already registered in class1. Now I have to add the next listener "Listener" in class2. And I should control, not to execute Listener1. Remarks: I cannot Change the code in class1 "Listener1".

Comment: @MilanBasnet: care to tell us more detail about the problem then? This solution would work for the problem as presented in your original post, and rather than force us to incrementally tease out shifting requirements from you, perhaps it would be best if you just told us all the important details up front.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy. `AbstractButton` has the method `getActionListeners()`. So you can remove any listener, added before. Then you can create your listener, which can call the another listener (which was removed from the button).
Something like this:

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
  private ActionListener anotherListener;
  public MyActionListener(ActionListener another) {
    anotherListener = another;
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    doSomething();
    if (myCondition) {
      anotherListener.actionPerformed(ae);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  One issue is that if somebody comes along _later_ to add yet another listener, you are in trouble.  This will work well, but only if you are sure that you are the _last_ Listener added.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact event you are firing, sometimes you can use `consume() / isConsumed()`.  (e.g. [java.awt.event.InputEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/))

Your listeners check for `isConsumed()` before doing anything, and call `consume()`.

In this way, only one listener will get the event, assuming that *they all follow this convention*.  So if one listener is from an outside or library class this won't help.  And the order of which Listener gets the event first may not be under your control.

So @Hovercraft's option may be better.  Depends on how decoupled you wish to be.

Comment: The doc says _"Only low-level, system events can be consumed"._ Is `ActionEvent` a low-level event?

Comment: Since we cannot control the order in which listeners are fired, I don't see this as a viable solution.

Comment: Can't we stop further code execution after Listener1 executes. so that Listener2 cannot execute.

Comment: @Milan: We could call System.exit() in Listener1, thereby stopping Listener2 from running.